# Excel preserving original dataset format

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how  can I open or import data from a dataset and preserves it's original column structure and formatting. For example, there are leading 0 in front of the numbers, and each column is exact width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Import it using Power Query (Get & Transform Data).  It is located in the Data tab in the ribbon.  This is the easiest and more user friendly method.  Just make sure that the columns are formatted as Text and not Number, this will preserve your leading zeros.